# re.sub group value

Tags: python, regex

How do I sub a group using `re.sub`?

I want it to override `3` with another value

> Current: `XYZ.Value = 3`;
>
> After: `XYZ.Value = 5`;

Right now my sub looks like this:

```
name = XYZ
value = 5
content = XYZ.Value = 5

re.sub(r'(%s\.Value\s*=\s*)([^;]+)' %name, r'\1 ' + value, content)
```

This is not working since it keeps adding a extra whitespace `' '` after overriding the value:

> `XYZ.Value =  5;`  **<---** 2 whitespaces instead of 1

I also tried using grouping `\g<2>`

```
re.sub(r'(%s\.Value\s*=\s*)([^;]+)' %name, r'\1\g<2>' + value, content)
```

But then then it keeps adding on the existing value without overriding it:

> Output: `XYZ.Value = 3`

Comment: Perhaps, `re.sub(r'(%s\.Value\s*=\s*)([^;]+)' %name, r'\g<1>' + value, content)` will do? You already capture all whitespace before `3` into Group 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `re.sub(r'(%s\.Value\s*=\s*)([^;]+)' %name, r'\g<1>' + value, content)` will do:

- Remove the space after the backreference as you already capture all whitespace before `3` into Group 1, and
- Use an unambiguous backreference (`\g<n>`) that allows using any digits after it.

See the [Python demo](http://ideone.com/LwjHxy):

```
import re
name = 'XYZ'
value = '5'
content = 'XYZ.Value = 5'
print(re.sub(r'(%s\.Value\s*=\s*)([^;]+)' %name, r'\g<1>' + value, content))
# => XYZ.Value = 5
```

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you could replace numbers with value '5':

```
>>> import re
>>> name = 'XYZ'
>>> value = 5
>>> content = 'XYZ.Value = 5'
>>> re.sub('\d+', str(value), content)
'XYZ.Value = 5'
```